# Qt crosscompilation for ARM

Tags: qt, arm, cross-compiling

Trying to build Qt5 from git sources under Linux host. My config args:

```
../qt5/configure -sysroot /home/r/variscite2/yocto_varsomam43_daisy/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/sysroots/varsomam43 -device linux-oe-g++ -no-xkb -no-xkbcommon -no-xkbcommon-evdev -no-sqlite -opensource -release -shared -skip qtwebengine -skip wayland -nomake tests -nomake examples -confirm-license  -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.03-20130313_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -prefix /usr/local/qt5-git -no-opengl
```

And device conf:

```
include(../common/linux_device_pre.conf)                                                                 

# I consider it a bug that this is required, but our EGL config.test _requires_ it
QMAKE_LFLAGS           += -Wl,-rpath-link,$$[QT_SYSROOT]

# The official opt vc EGL references GLESv2 symbols: need to link it
QMAKE_CFLAGS            = -march=armv7 -mtune=cortex-a9 -mfpu=neon
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS          = $$QMAKE_CFLAGS

DISTRO_OPTS            += hard-float
DISTRO_OPTS            += deb-multi-arch


CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.03-20130313_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
ROOTFS =/home/r/variscite2/yocto_varsomam43_daisy/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/sysroots/varsomam43

QMAKE_CC = $${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc
QMAKE_CXX = $${CROSS_COMPILE}g++
QMAKE_LINK = $${CROSS_COMPILE}g++
QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB = $${CROSS_COMPILE}g++
QMAKE_LINK_C = $${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc
QMAKE_AR = $${CROSS_COMPILE}ar cr
QMAKE_OBJCOPY = $${CROSS_COMPILE}objcopy
QMAKE_STRIP = $${CROSS_COMPILE}strip

QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE = -Wl,-O1,-rpath=$${ROOTFS}/usr/lib
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE += --sysroot=/home/r/variscite2/yocto_varsomam43_daisy/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/sysroots/varsomam43

QMAKE_INCDIR = $${ROOTFS}/usr/include

QMAKE_LIBDIR += $${ROOTFS}/usr/lib

QMAKE_INCDIR_X11 = $${ROOTFS}/usr/include
QMAKE_LIBDIR_X11 = $${ROOTFS}/usr/lib
QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL = $${ROOTFS}/usr/include
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL = $${ROOTFS}/usr/lib

include(../common/linux_arm_device_post.conf)

load(qt_config)
```

Configuration finishes successfully, but when I run `make` compilation begins with default host `g++` compiler not with cross-compiler. What is my mistake?

Comment: Did you perform a make clean?

Comment: I do build from clean building dir. Sources was cleaned by `git submodule foreach --recursive "git clean -dfx"` command.

Comment: Tried again on newly downloaded sources, same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, it builds some moc stuff with the host compiler. I experienced the same with my cross compiling lately.

When I saw, that make invokes the host g++, I immediately cancelled compilation. A friend told me to keep it running though, what I did. Surprisingly, the compilation went on, frequently switching between the host g++ for moc and the correct cross compiler for other stuff.

So I think that this is an intended behaviour.